# Uploaded laravel project to production server

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, storage, hosting

Uploaded laravel project to production server with problem can't find storage folder in public_html
can anyone help me ?

i have tried with php file to make symlink but it's not working

```php
<?php
$targetFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage/app/public';
$linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/public/storage';
symlink($targetFolder,$linkFolder);
echo 'Work Done';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have ssh access, You can run the given command to create a symlink, before running the command make sure you don't have any symlink already.

```
ln -s /home/USER/public_html/storage/app/public /home/USER/public_html/public/storage
```

For your reference, the syntax of the command is as **`ln -s source destination`**.

If you don't have access to ssh, You can do the same using cron job. Create a cron job with the above-given command and you'll get the symlink.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ProjectName/FileName/../..
```